# cakephp 2.2 testing with fixtures droptables false options creates database error Integrity viloating

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I am trying to create test cases for cakephp projects developed using the version 2.2.

I have done the login functionality using the auth component.

I have created the fixture to import the table data from the test database which I have created.

I have mocked the auth component to test my login functionality.

When I pass `invalid` username and password I am getting the message

> "Invalid username or password please try again."

Like that when I pass the `valid` username and password it gives the same message.  On further Investigating my tables where dropped from my test database too.  So I used the the public variable `"dropTable = " false` in this case getting the following error when running my controller test cases:

> "Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'"